# JQuery $.ajax - done() not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET/MVC site calling into WebApi webservices, using JQuery's $.ajax().  Most of these have been working fine, but I have one for which none of the callback functions - done(), fail(), always() - are being called.

The service is being called, and according to Fiddler, a response is being returned. But JQuery isn't calling any of the callback functions.

Other are working fine. Or seem to be.

The calling code is the same, in every case:

```
    core.callService = function (serviceUrl, httpType, token, data, failMessage, callback)
{
    try
    {
        var parameters = {
            type: httpType,
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: ajaxRequestTimeoutMS,
            headers: { "authenticationToken": "" + token }
        };

        if (httpType === "POST" || httpType === "PUT" || httpType === "DELETE")
        {
            parameters.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            parameters.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        else
        {
            parameters.data = data;
        }

        debugger;
        $.ajax(serviceUrl, parameters).done(
            function (result, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                debugger;
                // ...
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                debugger;
                // ...
            }).always(function ()
            {
                debugger;
                //whether success or failure
            });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        debugger;
        callback({
            success: false,
            message: e.message,
            data: null
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        debugger;
    }
};
```

Running Fiddler, I can see the request:

```
GET http://localhost:52057/api/MyController/myAction?myParameters HTTP/1.1
authenticationToken: eb76272e-b26e-4773-9d22-2218bea8beb1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:61986/Feedback?items%5B0%5D.updatetype=
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:52057
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ...
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcZGV2XFplYnVcWmVidV93ZWJcdHJ1bmtcWmVidV93c1xhcGlcRW1haWxUb29sXHNlbmRFbWFpbA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2015 16:43:32 GMT
Content-Length: 21

{"message":"Success"}
```

So the response is getting back to the client, but JQuery is not calling the done() function, or the fail() function, or the always() function. And I can't see why.  I've looked at the responses from other webservices, that are working, and I can't see anything different about them.

Any ideas?

=============Followup=============

More information, and more confusion.

If I call the webservice during the page init function, the callback is executed.  If I call it from within the click event of a button, it does not.

Looking at the requests and responses, the only difference I see is in the referer field of the request.  When I'm calling from the event function, I'm seeing "?items[0].updatetype=" appended to the URL.  And I can't see find who's doing that.

Comment: What version of mvc are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't matter.  The MVC server simply serves the html. We're having a problem between the client and the WebAPI server.

Comment: your right it shouldn't but it does this code should work in mvc v4 but in version 5 it won't had a similar problem which was fixed by serializing and using jquery load()

Answer (score 1):

OK, this one is just stupid.  After hours of digging through the JavaScript and monitoring the network traffic trying to figure out why the callback functions weren't executing...

The click event that called my webservice was being generated by a submit button.

Argh!